# Paginate resources failed

Tags: laravel

I have this resource :

```
class Job extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
         // the quantity of branch this job belongs to
        $branchesQuantity = BranchJob::where('job_id', $this->id)->count();

    // the quantity of countries this job belons to
    $countriesQuantity = JobCountry::where('job_id', $this->id)->count();

    // the translations of the job
    $jobTranslations = JobTranslation::where('job_id', $this->id)
       ->select('id', 'language_id', 'external_translation', 'internal_translation')->orderBy('language_id')->get();

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'short_name' => $this->short_name,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'branches_quantity' => $branchesQuantity,
        'countries_quantity' => $countriesQuantity,
        'job_translations' => $jobTranslations
    ];
}
}
```

And this code in my controller :

```
$queryJob = DB::table('jobs as j')
    ->join('job_translations as jt', 'j.id', 'jt.job_id');
```

... some other code

```
$jobs = $queryJob->get();
        return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

it works fine. It returns a correct json. Perfect.

I want to paginate the result, so I modify the query with :

```
    $jobs = $queryJob->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage);
return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

I have this error :

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Cannot use
> object of type stdClass as array in file
> /srv/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php
> on line 53

And don't understand why it works without pagination, and do not work with pagination.

Comment: Why do you pass $jobs intot JobResource::collection($jobs);

Comment: Hi Casper. If I want a json, it is mandatory to do like i did, no ? Or I did not understand how to use resouces ?

Comment: Accoring to documentation: The Laravel paginator result classes implement the Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable Interface contract and expose the toJson method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination results to JSON. You may also convert a paginator instance to JSON by simply returning it from a route or controller action https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#converting-results-to-json

Answer (score 0):

> The Laravel paginator result classes implement the
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable Interface contract and expose
>   the toJson method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination
>   results to JSON.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#converting-results-to-json

Therefore you can use,

```
return $queryJob->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage);
```

Laravel provides `forPage()` for collections however it is low-level.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-forpage

If your laravel version is < 5.5 then you can use `macro` to get same `paginate` behaviour.

https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

If version 5.5 => then you can pass paginator instance to the collection method of a resource or to a custom resource collection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#pagination

Comment: Yes it works like that. But I need to use ressources. So the question is still the same , how to paginate a collection of ressources with query builder. But perhaps it is not possible ? (I have a doubt).

Comment: You can use ForPage() https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forpage

Comment: @Dom what is your laravel version ?

Comment: I use Laravel 6

Comment: Please follow this way https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#pagination

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#pagination), you need to get the paginated result first and then transform to resource collection

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;

Route::get('/users', function () {
    return new UserCollection(User::paginate());
});
```

so you can use, something like

```
$jobs = $queryJob->paginate(10);
return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

Comment: It is exactly what I did but i have always the same error. It works with Eloquent query, but not with classic query builder. Strange.

Comment: @Dom Are you using `groupBy`, laravel don not support that in pagination, second thing is you have to create a eloquent model collection to convert it to api resource collection, if you are trying to use query builder, result, that will not work, better you should use relationship instead of query builder and joins for it.

Comment: I do not use groupBy. So I have to make my query with Eloquent and not with QueryBuilder. My question is now how to join 2 models with Eloquent + add some conditions on it. I will read the documentation.

Comment: @Dom, you need relationship between the models, yes, you can not use query builder, if you know tinker try to run `DB::table('your-table-name')->get()` and `YourModel::all()` and notice the difference, than you will understand the issue.

Comment: @Dom refer https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes I resolved the problem using a traditional query builder. And not an eloquent query. As it works fine now, I did not find another solution. But thanks you for your assistant. Dom

Comment: @Dom you should post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using a traditional query builder, and not an Eloquent query. As it works fine now, I did not find another solution.